# data not updating on laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel-5.4

Here is my edit.blade file.Please notice on From tag action attribute.Is this Ok?

```
         @extends('admin_theme.master')
         @section('title','Add Category')
      @section('content')
       @if(Auth::check())
       <script>
       function validselect(){
         var ind=document.getElementById('my_select').selectedIndex;
        if(ind==0){
        alert("please select an Valid Option");
                    }


                }
            </script>

            <div class="forms">
                <div class=" form-grids form-grids-right">
                    <div class="widget-shadow " data-example-id="basic-forms">
                        <div class="form-title">
                            <h4>Ready To ADD:</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-body">
                            <form class="form-horizontal" action={{route('category.update',$singledata->id)}} method="put">

                                {{ csrf_field() }}
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Category Name</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <input class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Name" type="text"  value="{{$singledata->name}}" name="name">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="inputPassword3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Status</label>
                                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                                        <Select  class="form-control" id="my_select"onchange="validselect()" name="status">
                                            <option>Select availability</option>
                                            <option value="1" @if($singledata->status==1){{"selected"}} @endif >Active</option>
                                            <option value="0" @if($singledata->status==0){{"selected"}} @endif>DeActive</option>

                                        </Select>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">

                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-offset-2"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" >Update</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        @endif
    @endsection
```

Here is my update method in controller and here the inputted data from edit page not found in $request object.I changed the html method like as PUT or PATCH but no luck :)

```
        public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            $allinput=$request->all();

            // dd($allinput);
           // dd($allinput);
            $data=Category::findorfail($id);
            $data->update($allinput);
            return view('admin_theme.dynamic_files.category.allCategory');
        }
```

here is my route

```
   <?php
    Route::get('/', function () {
        return view('my_theme.index');
    });
    Auth::routes();
    Route::get('/admin', 'HomeController@index');
    Route::resource('category','CategoryController');
```

In before (doing CRUD) the store() method works fine the problem is when i update data...i am stuck on this,please help me on this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Any Error you are getting?

Comment: no error just not update data :)

Comment: Can you show your category model

Comment: <?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $table="categories";   
    protected $fillable=['name','status'];
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast solved

adding  method="POST" in form tag and also add below line after {{csrf_field()}}

```
 <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
```

but why this line need ?dont know.If anyone make me understand i will be thankfull :)

Comment: Because CSRF protection is important: without it other websites could create requests to your website.